# Parsing Arduino Receiving Strings

Tags: serial, communication, string, data

I'm currently using google geolocation to get location data to one nodemcu and sending it through serial to another Arduino.
The serial command I'm getting right now is,

```cpp
1.450187T103.824745
```

I'm using the following code to parse it.

```cpp
 if (Serial.available())  {
    char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
    //if (c == '\n') {  //looks for end of data packet marker
    if (c == '\n') {
     // Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out
      //do stuff      
      substring = readString.substring(0,8);
      lati = substring;
      loc = readString.indexOf("T");
      substring = readString.substring(loc+1, loc+11);
     longi = substring;
       readString=""; //clears variable for new input
      substring=""; 

    }  
    else {     
      readString += c; //makes the string readString
    }
  }
```

It works most of the time but sometimes I get 'T' inside the string as well.
like this

```cpp
lat=1.450146&longi=102464T103
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: what is the reason for transmitting the `H`? ... you only need the `T` to separate the two values

Comment: Can you show us the actual serial String, that you received in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with readBytesUntil and C string

```
if (Serial.available()) {
  char buff[32];
  int l = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buff, sizeof(buff));
  if (l > 0 && buff[l - 1] == '\r') {
    l--; // to remove \r if it is there
  }
  buff[l] = 0; // terminate the string
  char* p = strchr(buff,'T'); // returns pointer in string
  if (p != NULL) {
    *p = 0; // write 0 as char at pointer to terminate the first part
    p++; // move the pointer to next char
    Serial.println(buff);
    Serial.println(p);
  } else {
    Serial.println(buff);
  }
}
```